# React error when form declared in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am doing a react. I just created this component called Input.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const Input = (label, placeholder) => {
  return (
    <label htmlFor={label}>
      {label}
      <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder} />
    </label>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

I imported it and used it in index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import input from "./components/Input.jsx";

const App = () => {
  const InputDrop = input("label", "placeholder");
  return (
    <div>
      <InputDrop />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This doesn't work and I [get this errors in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HVeV.png)

But, if I do it without declaring the form in a var, it works, like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import input from "./components/Input.jsx";

const App = () => {
  return <div>{input("label", "placeholder")}</div>;
};

export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I don't know why is not working. All type of help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: That's not what `htmlFor` is for. It should refer to the unique HTML `id` of the element it labels (in this case the `input`). Though if the label wraps the input, you can omit it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement/htmlFor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never invoke components like functions**. [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) does this  for you internally via the [`React.createElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) method as babel transpiles it for you during compilation.

1. React function components accept `props` as their first argument, which is an object of passed properties to the component. Using the ES6 destruct syntax:

   ```js
   // note the curly braces { } for destructuring
   const InputDrop = ({ label, placeholder }) => (
     <label htmlFor={label}>
       {label}
       <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder} />
     </label>
   )
   ```
2. You should  be passing props instead of invoking the component as a function directly

   ```js
   <InputDrop label="label" placeholder="placeholder" />
   ```

> But in general, without meaning to sound condescending it really sounds like you should give a thorough read of the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html), the very basics at least. Luckily for you, it's one of the best documentations out there, so it's pretty easy to read and learn.

Comment: Thnaks!! I didn't remember distructuring! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should either use it directly as a component

```
import Input from "./components/Input.jsx";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Input label="label" placeholder="placeholder"/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

(*but you would have to change its signature to `const Input = ({label, placeholder}) => {`*)

---

Or if you use it as a function, directly render the variable

```
const App = () => {
  const InputDrop = input("label", "placeholder");
  return (
    <div>
      {InputDrop}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Although for this case, it does not make much sense to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below approach

### Input Component

```
import React from "react";

const Input = ({label, placeholder}) => 
      <label htmlFor={label}>
      {label}
      <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder} />
    </label>

export default Input;
```

### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import input from "./components/Input.jsx";

const App = () => 
    <div>
      <Input label="label" placeholder="placeholder" />
    </div>

export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```